# Images inside a circle div overflow it's borders in Opera and Safari

Tags: overflow, css

I am trying to make circle divs with image links inside, the images are half the opacity and when hovered over they turn to full opacity (I'm doing that using jQuery). They work exactly how I want them to in Chrome, Firefox and IE, but they're acting really funny in Opera and Safari.

Here's a webdevout for the page:

http://www.webdevout.net/test?06

Here's the code that I have:

```
        <div class="cSpan">
           <h2 style="text-align: center;">Piercings</h2>
            <div class="circle">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/img03.png"></a>
            </div>
            <p> view more </p>
        </div>
```

and style

```
    .cSpan {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 280px;
        margin: -8em 3em 0 3em; }

    .circle {
        width:260px;
        height:260px;
        border-radius:50% 50% 50% 50%;
        overflow:hidden;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
        border: 10px solid #100000; }

    .circle img {
        margin-left:-50%;
        margin-top:-50%;
        opacity: 0.5; }
```

I've been pulling my hair out over this, so I hope I can get some help here, thanx! :)

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle or link to the actual page? You don't leave enough code to debug above.

Comment: I tried to make it work in jsfiddle but couldn't for some reason, but I edited my post and added a webdevout link to the page. And I actually decided to use a different approach to this, making the images as background images to the divs, but I'm having a hard time positioning them though, for some reason, but that's a different story.

Comment: its actually working fine for me in Safari. Which version are you having issues with? I think the Opera issue is it has trouble with clipping images that are inside an element with border-radius. I thought that was fixed though.

Comment: I was using the windows version of Safari, but then I was told that it's not a good idea. It worked fine on my roommates mac. Also I used the approach I mentioned in my previous comment and it works fine in all browsers now.

Comment: Windows Safari was discontinued with version 5.1. Mac Safari is now up to 6.0